# flutter TextField suffixText onclick event or any ontap method how to use

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

use in TextField and decoration in suffixText show text but need suffixText click event

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white10,
    hintText: 'Password',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.white),
    suffixText: 'forget?'.toUpperCase(),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Try using suffixWidget if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also an *suffix* property available in TextField. You can use it in place of *suffixText* and provide it either an *GestureDetector* or *InkWell* for the onTap method and give their child the Text Widget you are providing to suffixText.

```
        suffix:GestureDetector(
                onTap:(){},
                child:Text("Your Text"),
            ),
```

Comment: The argument type 'GestureDetector' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dartargument_type_not_assignable